# How to set Qt5::MacExtras to empty data? (CMake)

Tags: cmake, qt5, portability

In `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
if( "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" MATCHES "Darwin" )
    find_package( Qt5MacExtras ${QT_VERSION_REQ} QUIET )
endif()
...
...
target_link_libraries( MyApp Qt5::Widgets Qt5::MacExtras )
```

The MacExtras Qt5 package is thus optional. However, when the system will not be Mac, then Qt5::MacExtras will be undefined and CMake will report error. How can I set Qt5::MacExtras to empty data? I would use this in `else()` for the `if( "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}" MATCHES "Darwin" )`.